# Starting Rails app with NoSQL and using Postgresql during deploy or production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I would like to understand how I can start a rails app that is using NoSQL when I first make it and then when I deploy or have the project in production use Postgresql?

I'm really new to rails and have a project due in 4 days that requires me to have Postgresql once the app is deployed to Heroku.

Any information would be great, Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot just use PG from scratch?

Comment: you should use the same database across development and production otherwise there will be dragons

Comment: Good Points.  How about instead when I move from my local postgres server to the one on heroku, do I just update the UN/PW/Port and thats it?

Comment: are you using active record? If so, you can change your production database just through config/database.yml. But if you're using some custom noSql ORM then you will have to translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I truly Recommend you to use the same DB in development, testing and production environments. Otherwise you'll encounter many issues in terms of the schema file (generated by the migrations). It starts from simple strings length supported by PG or MySql (MySql limitations are bigger), and also for types like 'inet' in PG that should be converted to 'string' in MySql.
BTW- the inet type is created by Devise for 'user' (Which is the most popular gem for authentication) model! Even for that case you'll receive errors.

For a direct answer- you can simply change the database adapter in config/database.yml file.

But for my experience for some customers that explicitly asked for PG to MySql conversion (the opposite side, does not really matter), I would suggest using the same DB everywhere. Or else- dragons.